# Binding to dynamic route segment

Tags: ember.js, ember-router, computed-properties

I am trying to bind a computed property (or change via an observer) the `iso` dynamic segment in the `locale` route. The router I have is represented by:

```
this.route('locale', { path: '/:iso' }, function(){
    this.route('products', function() {
        this.route('single', { path: '/:id/:seoName' });
    });
});
```

Which results in URLs like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/en-us
http://localhost:4200/en-us/products
http://localhost:4200/en-us/products/123/product-name
```

What I'm wondering is if there is any way to programatically change the `en-us` part of the URL no matter which route you're on? My issue so far with just running a `transitionTo()` is that I have no way of knowing what the sub routes are from the current location.

Basically, I need a way of binding the `en-us` segment to a computed property I can that can update the URL automatically when it changes.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

To clarify further, I am looking for a way to update the URL segment **when a property changes**. Something like this:

- Navigate to: http://localhost:4200/en-us/products
- Service calls `this.set('locale', 'fr-ca')`
- Route detects updated `service.locale` property
- URL is updated to: http://localhost:4200/fr-ca/products

Comment: Do you have in your route refreshModel: true defined for iso param? I can provide en example of passing a computed property to controller based on iso but is that what you want?

Comment: @MirzaMemic no? Can you please provide an example? That sounds promising :D

Comment: As a follow-up, this is not for a query parameter specified as `?iso=en-us` but for the actual route segment in the URL itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Here is how you can pass param to your controller and then set a computed property on this.

First route

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  iso: null,
  queryParams: {
    iso: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },
  model(params) {
    this.set('iso', params.iso);
    return this.store.query('product', params); // do your query here to fetch products based on iso or whatever
  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('iso', this.get('iso'));
  }
});
```

So what I did here - I made param iso refresh model - when it is changed model will reload. This is optional. Also on this route I have created a property iso to store its value, since model is executed before setupController. This is just a trick to later pass its value to controller.

Now you have value iso from params into controller, and from there you can create a computed property from this value. Something like this:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  iso: null, //it will be set by its router
  isoComputed: Ember.computed('iso', function() {}) //do here a computed based on iso prop
}
```

This is a way to pass from router params to controller and inside controller set a computed which you can use in your templates.

Note sure if this is what you wanted but I hope it helps. Let me know...

EDIT

Your updated question has more sense. I think you can have a computed property on service, and do a redirect after it is changed, so something like this

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({ //you can do this on a route or controller
localization: Ember.inject.service('localization'),
locale: Ember.computed.oneWay('localization.locale'),
redirect: Ember.computed('locale', function() {
   let locale = this.get('locale');
   if(locale === "fr-FR") {
     this.transitionTo('products', { queryParams: { iso: 'fr-FR' }}); //you can redirect to whatever
   }
})
```

}

EDIT 2:

After more thinking service object should store transition values. This part should be moved to Mixin so it is easy to implement in each nested route. Then redirection after the prop is changed is stored in service so another prop like this:

```
params: Ember.computed.oneWay('localization.params'),
//inside redirect
this.transitionTo(...queryParams:{ this.get('params') } )....
```

Comment: I saw your comment later, but you can use this logic for any param that you have defined in your route. The trick here is that on Route which is just an ember object I am temp storing value that I read from params inside model and later passing to controller in setupController. After that setting computed on controller prop is easy,

Comment: Right this works going from URL -> Property. What I need is Property -> URL. I have added more notes to the OP. Hopefully that makes sense :) Thanks

Comment: That's closer but it won't work with the nested routes. Example being if we are at: `http://localhost:4200/en-us/products/123/product-name` and the locale changes, I need to be able to preserve the rest of the URL and just update `en-us` to the new value. Ie, the `transitionTo()` route is going to be variable depending on which route we're on...

Comment: Hm I would try to create an Mixin object that does redirection based on service injected. So you can add to your nested routes this mixin but I would say that service object should store full redirect values. So Store the transition values inisde service object so you can do a proper redirect?

Answer (score -1):

So after a ridiculous amount of trial and error, I have settled upon doing a `replaceWith()` on the router combined with a regex to swap out the old iso with the new one. I ended up with this:

```
/**
 * Locale changed
 *
 * @return  {null}
 */
localeChanged: function(){
    const locale = this.get('i18n.locale');
    const router = this.get('routing.router');

    var pathname = location.pathname.replace(/^\/[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}\//gi,'/' + locale + '/');
    router.replaceWith(pathname);
}.observes('i18n.locale').on('init')
```

Which then takes a full URL and redirects accordingly where:

```
http://localhost:4200/en-us/products/category/6/best-sellers
http://localhost:4200/en-us/products
```

becomes

```
http://localhost:4200/fr-ca/products/category/6/best-sellers
http://localhost:4200/fr-ca/products
```

Comment: This implementation is using observers. It is not recommended to use them since they are only for internal api.

Comment: False. Observers are a part of the documented guides for the latest Ember. They are not internal only. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/object-model/observers/

A computed property is not appropriate here as the property is never accessed therefore the computation will never occur. Since this is not a property of anything, an observer makes more sense to observe the change and act upon it.

Comment: Just for the reference if you look at Ember doc it states "Observers are often over-used by new Ember developers. Observers are used heavily within the Ember framework itself, but for most problems Ember app developers face, computed properties are the appropriate solution.". This is directly from documentation. I would also recommend that you look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PUX27RKCq0 which basically explains my point. But you can use whatever you want. I was just trying to help. cheers.

Comment: I apologize if I was coming off as if I was attacking you directly, that was not the intention. I appreciate your help, but that video does not apply for the use case here? Computed properties are specifically for values that change and/or are dependant on other values to return something. All of the use cases the video talks about are about using observers to set properties which is not what I'm doing here. I suppose what could also be done is convert `localeChanged` to a computed property and then in the `init()` do a `.get()` on it but is that not redundant when you can observe it instead?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something?